# How to format a huge textview?

Tags: android-studio, textview, android-xml

I want to make an app that has a history inside it, with paragraph, dialogs and titles. How can I do it without using HTML tags in Strings.xml? Is there a way to format that just using a TextView inside a ScrollView (because is the only way that I know) on Activity_main.xml?

Comment: Yes, pretty much that is basically what we do. Try studying the attributes/elements of textview and layouting(Linear Layout, Relative Layout, Constraint Layout, ...)

Comment: @L2_Paver So, if I have to write a huge text (like, 20 pages) I'll have to use HTML?

Comment: textview have an attributes `android:textsize` and `android:textStyle` you can predetermine the attributes in the xml layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="The point is, that's 20 minutes of your life you'll never get back. And here’s the really sobering statistic: If you want to be 99% certain of getting just one response – just one! – be prepared to send out 114 messages.

That’s one of the reasons OkCupid users exchange about 4 million messages – a day. That's roughly 166,666 messages being sent every hour – one of which was yours. And that’s just one site.

Think of all the Tinder, Bumble, Match.com etc… messages flying around out there. Your message has a lot of competition – especially when you’re messaging the most attractive local women.

No wonder online dating can quickly turn into the most frustrating part-time job you’ll ever have!

Let's assume the initial hurdles standing between you and meeting your ideal partner have been cleared – you've chosen a dating site, written an engaging profile, and selected the perfect profile picture.

You’re ready to skip all that frustration and wasted time, and start using cut  paste messages that will get you real results fast."/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Anytime you can find a way to establish common ground, jump on the opportunity. Studies have shown that people are more comfortable around those who remind them of themselves, and if she’s more likely to respond if she feels a bond with you right off the bat.

Connecting over the shared experience of using dating sites is one way to do it. You could also create a message built around cooking, swimming, dancing, reading – whatever subjects you have in common with your target woman.

Some dating sites like Match.com allow you to do keyword searches, so you can filter specifically for women who enjoy a particular hobby."/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: put your Text in string.xml and call it like this `android:text="@string/your_text"` rather than putting it directly.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I have to write a huge text (like, 20 pages) I'll have to use HTML?